# In which form add hash of document at the end of document

Tags: java, hash, digital-signature

I get byte array using:

```
byte[] digitalSignature = signature.sign();
```

So what is the best way to save this at the end of txt file or anyone file type, so that I can read it against when I verify sign. My idea is to make `String`: "Digital signature:" and add on this byte array in `String` form I tried this:

```
String stringAddOnEndOfDocument = new String("Digital signature:" + new String(digitalSignature));
```

When I read file, I find "Digital signature:", and read `String` after that and convert to byte array using `getBytes()` method, and then delete this from file.. But I can not verify signature of document with this.. I suppose that there is problem with conversion from bytes to string, but I do not what exactly..
Here is the code how I verify signature:

```
            deleteHashDataFromEndOfFile(testFile);
            
            byte[] messageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(testFile.toString()));
        

            signature.update(messageBytes);

            signature.verify(byteArray)
```

Comment: why do you want to store the hash in same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use a separate file, but if you really have to store the signature at the end of the file there are a few ways to do this.

Keep in mind that `new String(digitalSignature)` likely skips unprintable bytes and therefore destroys your signature. You need to handle it always as `byte[]` or encode it to a printable format using Hex or Base64 encoding.

Using "Digital Signature:" as a marker that the signature follows might work, but breaks if the actual text file contains exactly this text. To fix that you can either search the whole file for that text and only take the last occurrence, or you can to that in a binary fashion and store the signature always at the end. Since signatures usually always have the same length it works by slicing or copying only the last known bytes from the file. If there is a chance that the signature might have a variable length, you can designate the last 4 bytes for example as the length of the signature and be sure that the signature is exactly before that.

You can use `int lengthOfSignature = new BigInteger(theLast4Bytes).intValue()` to read the value and write it with `BigInteger.valueOf(lengthOfSignature).toByteArray()` (make sure that it is 4 bytes long and if necessary pad with 0x00 bytes at the front). When reading the signature length your code should test whether the number makes sense: is positive and in a range that you expect 255-257 bytes for example. After that it is only a little bit of index math to get the signature.

Writing might look like this:

```
byte[] messageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
byte[] signature = sign(privateKey, messageBytes);
byte[] signatureLength = BigInteger.valueOf(lengthOfSignature).toByteArray();
byte[] messageOutput = new byte[messageBytes.length + signature.length + 4];

System.arraycopy(messageBytes, 0, messageOutput, 0, messageBytes.length);
System.arraycopy(signature, 0, messageOutput, messageBytes.length, signature.length);
System.arraycopy(signatureLength, 0, messageOutput, messageBytes.length + signature.length + 4 - signatureLength.length, signatureLength.length); // padding included
// TODO write messageOutput to file
```

Reading and verifying the signature would look like this:

```
byte[] msgAndSigBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
byte[] signatureLengthBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(msgAndSigBytes, msgAndSigBytes.length-4, msgAndSigBytes);
int signatureLength = new BigInteger(signatureLengthBytes).intValue();
// TODO check for proper size according to your signature algorithm
byte[] signature = Arrays.copyOfRange(msgAndSigBytes, msgAndSigBytes.length-4-signatureLength, msgAndSigBytes-4);
byte[] msgBytes = Arrays.copyOf(msgAndSigBytes, msgAndSigBytes.length-4-signatureLength);
boolean success = verify(publicKey, signature);
```

If the file is large then streams should be used. When writing, then normal input or output streams can be used, but reading would either require seekable streams or multiple passes.